# Symfony3 Translation System Cache to Memcache

Tags: symfony, memcached, php-7, symfony-3.1

I have found so far an bundle that uses memcache as translation source but I haven't found anything on how to move the translation cache from disk storage to a service or directly to memcache.
I have also look at the options for the framework but I haven'T found anything useful on it (or I'm to stupid to use google ^^).

I need to move the cache files to memcache for deployment reason.
I'm having multiple Application Servers.
And to store the translation cache etc. on disk is slow and pane full if I deploy software (php Process on the productive app servers need to be restarted). It would make my live easier if that stuff would be stored in memcache as I would simply flush memcache to reset the translation stuff.

did anyone ever try this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What first comes to the mind is to make a console command that would use one Loader (for example, `\Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\XliffFileLoader`) and then another Dumper (something implementing `\Symfony\Component\Translation\Dumper\DumperInterface` from that bundle, like `MemcacheDumper`).

In your command your would load translations from one source by loader (in the form of `\Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageCatalogue`) and then dump them into another.

Comment: Hmmmm, my intension is not the loading part. I store my translations in the database and distribute the changes through doctrine migration bundle. I need to replace the file caches inside the translation directory.

Comment: Well I have 5 separated application servers. I currently solve the issue by sharing the cache directory over nfs, but I would prefer to remove this.

Comment: Something else: the number of application servers is variable as they are separated out on on demand servers.

Comment: How does it matter how many servers you have? Don't take it like sarcasm, it is not, I truly don't understand. Once you have changed something in configuration or code --> drop & warm-up the cache. Why would you not stick the rule?

Comment: Well I would have to login to every application server and execute this as I don't want a nfs shared cache directory.
The source itself is located on an nfs shared directory to the web/application servers. each application server has its own cache directory.

Comment: I think I'm going to solve it with my deployment script.